# Play Eclipse breakpoint audio without stopping

Tags: eclipse, debugging, audio

I'd like to attach different sounds to various lines of code, then run the code without stopping.  The ear can sometimes recognize a broken pattern quickly.  For example nested loops can issue different "tick" sounds: (audio:) Hi lo lo lo Hi lo lo lo Hi lo lo  - ooops missing that last "lo".

Right now I use "Breakpoint Properties... > Actions > Sound Action" to associate a brief sound clip with a breakpoint.  But the program halts when it hits that breakpoint.  I want to hear the audio without having it halt execution at the breakpoint.

Comment: Came here to find an answer to the same question. Did you find anything yet?